# Cofinality and the Continuum

Tags: set-theory

I know we know what the cofinality of the Continuum is not, i.e. it is not $\aleph_0$. Is there a "favorable" method out there for indicating (I don't want to say "showing") either of the following:

(cf)c = *X*

(cf)*X* = c

... where *X* is some otherwise given cardinal (not the same in both equalities listed; I'm not saying the cofinality of the continuum has to be equivalent to the continuum, or *vice versa*)? I.e. have sound and valid arguments been given for at least one value of said *X*, or at least a "plausibility range" for values of *X*?

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking here. It’s consistent with ZFC that the cofinality of the continuum be any regular cardinal except $\aleph_0$ (since in particular  it’s consistent that the continuum *be* any regular cardinal other than $\aleph_0$). It is also consistent that the continuum be singular, in which case it is not the cofinality of any cardinal.

Comment: (If the continuum is regular it is the cofinality of itself, and also of $\aleph_c$ and $\aleph_{\omega_c}$, etc. But it is consistent that both if these are equal to $c$, or that they are both larger. There are so many possibilities.)

Comment: (And many more that are provably larger than $c$: the limit of any sequence of $c$ ordinals will have cofinality $c$... e.g. $\beth_c$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a precise sense, $\mathfrak{c}$ can have whatever cofinality we want it to, other than $\omega$:

> Suppose $M$ is a countable model of ZFC and $\alpha$ is (in the sense of $M$) an uncountable regular cardinal. Then there is a forcing extension $M[G]$ with the same regular cardinals in which $cf(\mathfrak{c})=\alpha$.

*(The countability hypothesis is only to guarantee that forcing extensions actually exist; if you're familiar with the approach to forcing via Boolean valued models, we can appropriately drop the countability hypothesis.)*

This is a consequence of the flexibility of the *exact value* of the continuum: by adding $\kappa$-many Cohen reals for $\kappa$ sufficiently large (that is, greater than $\mathfrak{c}$), we ensure $cf(\mathfrak{c})^{M[G]}=cf(\kappa)^{M[G]}=\alpha$ (the second inequality being a consequence of the very nice properties of Cohen forcing).

So, for example, there's no hope of proving something like $cf(\mathfrak{c})=\omega_1$ or similar. Indeed, very strange phenomena are possible - for instance, $\mathfrak{c}$ could be singular!

Comment: Alright, well, my my next question here is: would it be less "rough"/"begging the question" to assume a specific cofinality for $\mathfrak{c}$ than an outright cardinality? (Of course, this requires a double assumption that the Continuum "has" a cofinality as such.) Or if we could assume the cofinality, we could too easily deduce the cardinality? [The meta-idea would be that we want a formula or something, for getting to the Continuum in the first place also, that is not too easy to come up with.]